# Storing hindi text in python list

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8

I need to store Hindi words in a python list. When I store Hindi word , its being stored as utf-8 encoded string and not the actual word. Though if I traverse through the list, I am able to print words in Hindi but when I print list , it shows utf-8 encoded strings.

This is what I am getting when i print list 'tags'

```
['\xe0\xa4\x9f\xe0\xa5\x8d\xe0\xa4\xb0\xe0\xa5\x88\xe0\xa4\xab\xe0\xa4\xbf\xe0\xa4\x95 \xe0\xa4\xaa\xe0\xa5\x81\xe0\xa4\xb2\xe0\xa4\xbf\xe0\xa4\xb8\xe0\xa4\x95\xe0\xa4\xb0\xe0\xa5\x8d\xe0\xa4\xae\xe0\xa4\xbf\xe0\xa4\xaf\xe0\xa5\x8b\xe0\xa4\x82',  '\xe0\xa4\xb5\xe0\xa5\x87\xe0\xa4\xb8\xe0\xa5\x8d\xe0\xa4\x9f \xe0\xa4\x9c\xe0\xa4\xbf\xe0\xa4\xb2\xe0\xa4\xbe','\xe0\xa4\x9c\xe0\xa5\x80\xe0\xa4\x8f\xe0\xa4\xb8\xe0\xa4\x9f\xe0\xa5\x80', '\xe0\xa4\xa6\xe0\xa4\xbf\xe0\xa4\xb2\xe0\xa5\x8d\xe0\xa4\xb2\xe0\xa5\x80', '\xe0\xa4\xb6\xe0\xa4\xbf\xe0\xa4\x95\xe0\xa4\xbe\xe0\xa4\xaf\xe0\xa4\xa4']
```

where as expected output is

```
[ट्रैफिक पुलिसकर्मियों, वेस्ट जिला, जीएसटी,दिल्ली,शिकायत]
```

Answer (score 2):

Everything in a computer is bytes, all the data going into or out of any program you write, is bytes.

The problem with bytes is that by themselves they are meaningless, we need conventions to give them meaning.
Using ASCII code every byte is assigned one of 95 symbols. for example a= '\x61', if you using a function print you will see `char a` not `\x61`, but in reality you using the code of the byte
then if you want just show the data of your list, use print function :

```
## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

for i in your list :
    print i
```

The output of this code is meaningfull

```
## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

for i in your list :
    i
```

The output of this code is bytes

Answer (score 1):

The `str()` of a list is built up from the `repr()` of its elements - you wouldn't necessarily be able to tell where the elements begin and end otherwise.  And the `repr()` of a string uses escape sequences for non-ASCII characters, to make sure you can tell exactly what's in the string even in the presence of various types of nonprintable characters.

You just need to convert the list to a string yourself, without involving `repr()`:

```
', '.join(tags)
```

Answer (score 0):

decode list to utf-8 before print or store it to get actual string

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

my_list = [ट्रैफिक पुलिसकर्मियों, वेस्ट जिला, जीएसटी,दिल्ली,शिकायत]

print my_list.decode('utf-8')
```

## Output

```
[ट्रैफिक पुलिसकर्मियों, वेस्ट जिला, जीएसटी,दिल्ली,शिकायत]
```

Comment: Can you explain it more